# android install shortcut but shortcut icon is not showing

Tags: android

I'm trying to create app shortcut, i refer to some documents and i'm using

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
launchIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, new Intent(getApplication(), MainActivity.class));
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "test app");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
```

also i add permission to my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

however, it works fine on one of my old htc phone(android 4.4), but not on another phone which is samsung s6 (android7.0).

Can anyone help me? thx!

Comment: Is this your own app? Is there a reason that you are not doing this from the AndroidManifest instead?

Answer (score 0):

- The permission model/workflow has been changed from API 23 – Android M or Higher than.
- You should try to new runtime permission model has been introduced. According to this model, users are not prompted for permission at the time of installing the app, rather developers need to check for and request permission at runtime

  ```
  if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

   if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT)) {
          AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
          builder.setTitle("Need Permission");
          builder.setMessage("This app needpermission.");
          builder.setPositiveButton("Grant", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                  dialog.cancel();
                  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT}, INSTALL_SHORTCUT);
              }
          });
          builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                  dialog.cancel();
              }
          });
          builder.show();
  ```

You Can Use That Code also:~

```
public static void addShortcut(Context context)
{
    Intent shortcut = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");

    ApplicationInfo appInfo = context.getApplicationInfo();


    shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "appInfo.name");
    shortcut.putExtra("duplicate", false); 


    ComponentName component = new ComponentName(appInfo.packageName, "MainActivity.class");
    shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).setComponent(component));


    ShortcutIconResource iconResource = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(context, appInfo.icon);
    shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, iconResource);

    context.sendBroadcast(shortcut);
}
```

Comment: thx i was wondering if it's permission problem as well, but since protection level of shortcut installing is normal, it doesn't need to be granted during runtime i think. i've tried same function in whatsapp and it doesn't ask me before creating shortcut either

Answer (score 0):

**Use Method to reduce confusion .Try this it will work**

```
public void createShortCut(){
    Intent shortcutintent = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    shortcutintent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
    shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getString(R.string.shortcutname));
    Parcelable icon = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.icon);
    shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, icon);
    shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EnterActivity.class));
    sendBroadcast(shortcutintent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you did mistake is you should give `Intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);` to EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT Intent.

You can use this below method to create or remove Shotcuts

```
private void createOrRemoveShortcut(String name, boolean create) {

    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), ShortCutActivity.class);

    shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

    Intent addIntent = new Intent();
    addIntent
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, name);


    if (create) {
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
                Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getActivity(),
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher));

        addIntent
                .setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");

        addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);  //may it's already there so don't duplicate
    } else {
        addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    }


    getActivity().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
}
```

Make sure your ShortCutActivity has `android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT` in mainfest file

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.activity.ShortCutActivity"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_sample"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

If you want to remove shortcut, you should have following permission add it in mainfest,

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i make it work, i'm not sure which one of the following made it, but what i've changed is this line

```
new Intent(getApplication(), MainActivity.class));
```

i add additional category and action on it

```
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
```

and it's working.